# conditional sentence:Type 2 vs type 3

Tags: conditional-constructions

Context from an article: "People here are really fat. It's because parents here give mobile phones to young kids. I think ..

> 1. If **they did not do it**, kids would be of normal weight
> 2. If **they had not done it**, kids would be of normal weight
> 3. If **they had not done it**, kids would have been of normal weight

I can't decide which of the above is/are right continuation(s).

Comment: What is your question, please?

Comment: Probably which sentence should be used given the context. Prof-Wiz: I've edited your question – if that's not what you intended to ask, feel free to [edit] it yourself.